# Can NAO speak local languages?

Tags: text-to-speech, nao-robot

I want the NAO to be able to speak local language 'Hindi' which is not provided by Aldebaran Robotics. Is there a way to make the robot speak language other than officially supported, maybe by installing TextToSpeech Engine by ourselves. Any suitable pointers in this direction would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could use an external TextToSpeech:

- a binary, directly if it's alsa compatible, as NAO is a gentoo linux onto alsa driver.
- using a C++ lib and recompiling it using the NAOQi module: ALAudioDevice.sendAudioBuffer*.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you can connect NAO with the TTS of Google translate.